# Export available page layout fields

Tags: page-layout, excel

I have around 110 profiles in my org and at least 8 page layouts assigned to different profiles containing over 300+ fields each. 
This development has been old now and many fields are inactive which I can't remove from object due to trigger and workflows related to them but need to remove them from page layouts,

**How do I export all available fields in particular page-layout in spreadsheet to compare and identify?**

Even exporting API names from layout will do the trick, I just need to know which fields are available in what page layout without putting all fields manually in spreadsheet.

Comment: I've had some success doing this in Microsoft Excel. Use the Force.com IDE to pull those layouts out, then write a fairly verbose VisualBasic macro to read those files, load them in the XML reader class, and finally process the XML node by node and put those results into a spreadsheet. I don't have that script anymore, and this isn't really an answer, but if you're desperate, you could cobble this together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Force.com IDE in Eclipse](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE), you can get an XML file for all your Page Layouts. If you then open the layout file in Excel, you can see a list of the fields in a friendly way.

[image: Project Properties]
[image: Select Metadata]

Comment: I use eclipse for coding but never used eclipse for exporting these things, I tried to find layouts but couldn't find them. Under what folder I can find that?

Comment: @AnkzDavé See screenshots in my answer. You usually select which types of metadata (objects, page layouts, classes etc.) you pull down from the server, when you set up the project. But you can also select more as in the screenshots.

Comment: The output wasn't simple as you mentioned, I had to go through the different fields in excel sheet, in my case I had 60 rows and columns till AH but this solution gave result closest to what I wanted where I could find field names and related lists including their visible fields so I'll up-vote this solution but won't mark that as a solution yet till I'm done with all possible investigation, but if nothing else is out there then this'll be the answer of my question
P.S. I copied text from page layouts and that worked as copy paste content but this solution provided by you gives related lists

Comment: @AnkzDavé did you find a better solution?

Comment: Not yet, I just copied from page layout editing page and paste that in spreadsheet.