# export profiles with all field level security to an xls

Tags: profile, excel

need an overview from all profiles and their fls and want to export this to xls?
I tried to do this with a similiar question [Export available page layout fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91963/export-available-page-layout-fields/227137#227137)

I don't know what to do after the last step. What do I need to do after I used the button for "project properties"? How do I get a single xml file, or preferably an xls file, where I can see all profiles with their field level security?

Can someone provide me with guidance?

Comment: The "last step" being export from Eclipse or import to Excel from an xls file? Can you clarify what the "last step" means to you?

Comment: what do d i need to do after i used the button project properties ? how to get a single xml or preferably xls file where i can see all profiles with all their fls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that post is trying to tell you is that when you use Eclipse to create a new project you use Project Properties to select what you want to include in the new project. As a result of your selection, that's what is included in the package.xml that is created. You can copy that file from the location in your project folders as shown below (package.xml is under Src near the bottom) and open it in Excel to obtain the information that you're looking for.

[image: Eclipse Project File Structure]

Comment: Thank you very much Crmprogdev, this is really helping. I have one last question though, when i open the file in excel i only have the profiles, but not all the field settings, is there a way to also get the fields?

Comment: @JérômePijpers I'd expect you to also need at least all of the "Object" `Settings` and perhaps the `Objects` too. You might want `Permissions`. If you have `Permission Sets` and `Record Types`, if those are not included in `Object Settings`, you may need to add those as well along with `Page Layouts` so the assignments will show up in the Profiles. As I've not done this particular exercise, you may need to add and remove metadata from your project until you have all of what you want to see.

Comment: Thank you CrmProgDev, Im trying to figure it out, my Eclipse is freezing a lot but im sure your explanation will solve my issue!

Comment: @JérômePijpers You're quite welcome. If Eclipse is freezing, You may want to make certain you're closing down as much of everything else as possible and have at least Eclipse Neon installed on your machine for compatibility. Sounds like it could be a low memory issue, but also check for Java updates too.